# How do I cp the folder, not just the folder content?

Tags: linux, freebsd, osx, cp

Let's say I have folder structure like this:

```
/parentFolder/
  folder1/
    folder1.1/
      file1
  folder2/
    file2
```

How do I copy folder2 inside folder1.1 so that file2 is also in

```
/parentFolder/folder1/folder1.1/folder2/file2
```

ie so that the folder structure looks like this:

```
/parentFolder/
  folder1/
    folder1.1/
      folder2/
        file2
      file1
  folder2/
    file2
```

?

If I just go `cp -R /parentFolder/folder2 /parentFolder/folder1/folder1.1` then it copies the *content* of the folder2, but I want to copy folder2 as well.

Related question: would the answer applies to `mv` as well?

Comment: What kind of Linux are using? from what i know it takes this `cp -R /parentFolder/folder2/* /parentFolder/folder1/folder1.1` to move only the content

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cp -R parentFolder/folder2 parentFolder/folder1/folder1.1/folder2`

Comment: This works but it's totally redundant to type folder2 in my machine.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by redundant?

Comment: It's not needed. Even with `$cp -R parentFolder/folder2 parentFolder/folder1/folder1.1/`, it works the same way.

Comment: oh, yes... indeed. But I have just set it there make sure it works for him

Comment: This is the one and only answer!

Answer (score 1):

Which `cp` are you using? UNIX tools are sort of similar among different systems, but may behave differently in some situations.

GNU `cp` has the behavior you want. BSD `cp` has the behavior you describe. Try removing the slash from the first argument, and writing:

`cp -R /parentFolder/folder2 /parentFolder/folder1/folder1.1`

rather than:

`cp -R /parentFolder/folder2/ /parentFolder/folder1/folder1.1`

According to wikipedia[(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp_%28Unix%29), this is how BSD `cp` does what you want.

Comment: You've got that backwards, appending a slash causes the contents of the directory to be copied. hobbes3 must use `…/folder2` and not `…/folder2/`.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use `rsync` for this kind of action. On top of copying the files it can copy permissions and improve the transfer speed over conventional `cp`.

The trailing `/` on the destination is crucial for your requirement.

Try something like:

```
rsync -aHSv /parentFolder/folder2 /parentFolder/folder1/
```